# parameterized query without preparing statement in PHP

Tags: php, ado.net, prepared-statement, parameterized-query

Is there an API in MySQLi, PDO or in PHP that use parameterized query but not preparing it for recall later? I found it in ADO.NET when we dont call [.Prepare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) method of SQLParameter, but I didn't find this in PHP.

Comment: what do you want or require functionality wise. ? if you dont want to prepare a statement just use mysqli->query

Comment: I don't understand your requirements either, why don't you just prepare the statement and execute it?

Comment: @molvi. prepared statement is utility for executing query multiple times. think that i want to execute a query for single time. so i don't want to having unnecessary overhead on Database for preparing it. such as caching query plan in memory

Comment: @markus. look [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbprogramming/prepared-statements-sqlapp.html#nowhere). it also say:" Do not prepare statements that are used only once. In general, you should not prepare statements if they are only executed once. There is a slight performance penalty for separate preparation and execution, and it introduces unnecessary complexity into your application."

Comment: I have never heard that guideline before. Parameterized queries are a security measure, if I must prepare a statement in order to use parameterized queries I don't care about a slight performance impact which most probably is not substantial. That said I don't know if you can use parameterized queries without preparing a statement, in PDO, I have never seen such a thing done.

Comment: @ahoo This is definitely not possible, the underlying MySQL C-API that powers all MySQL access mechanisms does not support it. There is no way this can be implemented in PHP because of a limitation of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are sent to the database server with the values separated from the query. If you wanted to get the user with ID 1337, using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) you would do this;

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.id, u.username FROM users u WHERE u.id = :theUserIdToGet LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':theUserIdToGet', 1337);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

In a traditional query this would just be;

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.id, u.username FROM users u WHERE u.id = ' . 1337 . ' LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

The first example clearly requires more code, however it has the following benifits;

- Security - The values (just one in this case; 1337) are sent to the database server separately. The database server safely checks these values for bad characters and inserts them into the query before execution. Note that some query API's will emulate this, but it still offers a great deal of safety.
- Readability - When adding more than a couple of parameters to a query, it gets very messy if concatenating strings ("WHERE id = " . $var1 . " AND " . $var2 . " = 1", etc).
- Performance (occasionally) - It is true that prepared statements are vastly quicker when executed many times, but in practice this is very infrequent. The performance overhead of preparing a query over query() is negligible.

Prepared statements should always be used when inserting variables into a query because of their legibility and security.

PDO is generally considered to be very good, I personally use it all the time. It's learning curve is gentle and many tutorials are available on the internet. It's documentation is [here](http://php.net/pdo)